# Maximal Cohen Macaulay modules over regular factor rings.

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay-rings

Hi,

my question is simple. Let (R,m) be a commutative regular local noetherian ring. Is it true that for every prime p \in Spec(R), the factor ring R/p has maximal cohen-macaulay R/p-module?

Best Regards,
David

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, certainly in the geometric case (that is $R$ is essentially of finite type over a field), Hochster proved the existence of Big Cohen-Macaulay modules. But the existence of finitely generated CM modules is open even in dimension three in the geometric case.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is certainly true if $p$ is generated by a regular sequence. In this case, $R/p$ is regular, local and hence Cohen Macaulay. Hence, $R/p$ is a maximal Cohen Macaulay module over $R/Ann(R/p)$. But $Ann(R/p)=p$ since $p$ is prime. So, $R/p$ is a maximal Cohen Macaulay $R/p$-module.

Essentially, all you need is for $R/p$ to be Cohen Macaulay. But probably weaker conditions might suffice (Edit: Also, $R/p$ is Cohen Macaulay when $R$ is regular, local, iff $p$ has height $1$)

The question is similar to small Cohen-Macaulay module conjecture where we ask the same question over a complete local ring (which I believe is open)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right. But what if p is not generated by a regular sequence?

Comment: I'm dealing with the situation when R/p is not Cohen-Macaulay ring.

Comment: I am not sure yet, but I will think about it. .

Comment: I agree that this is quite close to small Cohen-Macaulay module conjecture. But I'm dealing with "special" rings of the shape R/p, where R is regular and p is prime. So I hope that this conjecture is solved for these rings.

Comment: @David: it does not matter, if you can solve this for primes, you can solve it for any quotient $R/I$ by looking a minimal prime of $I$ of maximal dimension. 

Comment: @Hailong: So you say that if there is maximal CM for every ring R/p (p \in Spec(R)), then there is maximal CM for every ring R/I (I ideal of R)? (btw thank you for your comment).

Comment: @David: that's right. Perhaps you know this already, but the conjecture is true for dimension at at most 2 and open in dim 3. 

Comment: @Hailong: I'm interested in dimensions \geq 4. For R regular local of dim=3, I'm quite sure that R/p is a CM ring for every p \in Spec(R) so this conjecture is also true in dimension 3. Somebody told me that this is true even in dimension 4 since R/p has a canonical module, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @David: I meant dimension of $R/p$ is at most 2. From this it is easy to deduce that if dimension of $R$ is $4$, the conjecture is true. In this case, if $R/p$ is dimension 3, then $p$ is height 1, so principal.

Comment: David, if R has dim 4, then the only interesting case is dim R/p=2 (if it's 1, R/p is a domain so CM; if it's 3, then p is principal).  The S2-ification -- endom ring of canonical module $\mathrm{Ext}^2_R(R/p,R)$ -- is then a MCM module.

Comment: On the larger question, the small CM module conjecture is wide open for complete local rings (in fact it's false for trivial reasons if the ring is not catenary, so complete is a standard assumption) and the assumption that $p$ is prime is not of any particular help.  Your question is basically the small CMs conjecture.

Comment: Thank you all. So this is completely open if dim(R/p) is \geq 3 (for example R regular local of dim=5 and p of height 2)? 

Comment: @David, yes, I think so. 

Comment: I see that I left out part of what I meant to say above: since for the small MCMs conjecture we assume the ring is complete, it is a quotient of a regular ring by Cohen Structure.  So your question is exactly the small MCMs conjecture for domains.