# Homologically nice commutative rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

> Let $R$ be a commutative regular local ring. Is it true that for every $\mathfrak p \in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ there is a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ such that $\mathrm{projdim}(M)=\mathrm{ht}(\mathfrak p)$ and $\mathrm{Ass}(M)=\{\mathfrak p\}$?
>
> Or is there some family of commutative noetherian rings where is this true?

I know that this holds if $R$ is commutative regular local of Krull dimension $\leq 4$ (up to dimension 3 it was easy, because factor rings $R/\mathfrak p$ where always CM, so we can take $M=R/\mathfrak p$. Dimension 4 was harder and in dimension 5 or more I don't know).

Is this an easy/hard/hopeless/already open/similar to something problem?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you care about this? Also, is it the finite generation part that is the toughie here?

Comment: @Keerthi: I think the tough part is to assure that `${\rm Ass}(M)=\{p\}$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My feeling is that this is really about set-theoretic complete intersections.

Let $X={\rm Spec} A$ be a noetherian affine scheme such that every irreducible subscheme of $X$ is a set-theoretic complete intersection. In other words, for any prime $\mathfrak p\subset A$, there exist a set of elements $x_1,\dots,x_t\in \mathfrak p$ such that $t={\rm ht} (\mathfrak p)$ and the $x_1,\dots,x_t$  generate a $\mathfrak p$-primary ideal with $\mathfrak p= \sqrt{( x_1,\dots, x_t)}$, or equivalently the zero set $Z(x_1,\dots,x_t)=\overline{\{\mathfrak p\}}$.

In this case, take $M=A/(x_1,\dots,x_t)$ has the property that ${\rm Ass} (M)=\{\mathfrak p\}$.

If in addition $A$ is CM, then so is $M$ and then its projective dimension satisfies
that
$$
{\rm pd} (M)=\dim A-\dim M= {\rm ht} (\mathfrak p).
$$

I suppose the next step is to look at an affine scheme with an irreducible subscheme that is not a set-theoretic complete intersection and see what happens there.

(**Addendum**)

Regarding the case when there exists an irreducible subscheme that is not a set-theoretic complete intersection, one may mention, that in general, (still assuming that $A$ is CM, which follows if it is regular),
$$
{\rm pd} (M)=\dim A-{\rm depth}_A M.
$$
If furthermore ${\rm Ass} (M)=\{\mathfrak p\}$, then it follows that 
$$
{\rm depth}_A M \leq \dim M = \dim A - {\rm ht} (\mathfrak p),
$$
So ${\rm pd} (M)\geq {\rm ht} (\mathfrak p)$ with equality iff $M$ is CM.
In other words, your desired condition is to find a CM module whose only associated prime is $\mathfrak p$.

At least for modules generated by a single element this seems to be pretty close to $\overline{\{\mathfrak p\}}$ being a set-theoretic complete intersection as 
for an ideal $\mathfrak q\subseteq A$ in a noetherian ring the following holds:
$$
\mathfrak q \text{ is $\mathfrak p$-primary} \Leftrightarrow {\rm Ass}(A/\mathfrak q)=\{\mathfrak p\}.
$$
One way to ensure that $A/\mathfrak q$ is CM is to make sure that $\mathfrak q$ has the right number of generators and in order to have the condition on the associated primes one would need that $\mathfrak q$ is $\mathfrak p$-primary. Of course, I am not claiming that this is the only way to produce such modules, but this seems to be the obvious way.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree with this implication. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46872/primary-regular-sequences. I take a look at the reversed implication. Thank you.

Comment: Just for sure. So complete intersection can be translated to this: for any prime $p \subset A$, there exists a set of elements $x_1, \dots, x_t \in p$ such that $t=ht(p)$ and the $x1, \dots, xt$ generate a $p$-primary ideal? Thank you.

Comment: David, this is *set-theoretic* complete intersection. A complete intersection would mean that the ideal itself is generated by ${\rm ht}(p)$ number of elements.

Answer (score 7):

OK, so this is weaker than your [last question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46872/primary-regular-sequences), which is false but related to some open problems and also weaker than the conjecture in your [first question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46497/maximal-cohen-macaulay-modules-over-regular-factor-rings) which is another famous open problem. All of these sound like a nice project (-:.

The short anwser is this one is also open in general. I will show that your statement, if true for all regular local ring, would imply one of the outstanding open problem, the so-called [Serre's Positivity conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_multiplicity_conjectures). I will sketch the proof below.

Suppose your statement is true for any regular local ring $(R,m)$. Let $p,q$ be such that $\sqrt{p+q} =m$ and $\dim R/p + \dim R/q = \dim R$. By your statement, we can choose Cohen-Macaulay module $M,N$ such that $Ass(M)= \{p\}$ and  $Ass(M)= \{q\}$. Let:

$$\chi(M,N) = \sum_{i\geq 0} (-1)^i\text{length}(\text{Tor}_i^R(M,N))$$

the Serre's intersection multiplicity.

Then $M\otimes N$ has finite length and $M,N$ are Cohen-Macaulay,  and  a classical result by Serre (can be found in his book Local Algebra, V.6, Theorem 4, p 110 of the English version) says that $\text{Tor}_i^R(M,N)=0$ for $i>0$, so

$$\chi(M,N) =\text{length}(M\otimes N)>0$$

(This is a nice generalization of Bezout theorem, since curves are Cohen-Macaulay)

But since $Ass(M)= \{p\}$ one has a prime filtration of $M$ by $a>0$ copies of $p$ and primes of smaller dimensions. Similarly $N$ has a filtration with $b>0$ copies of $q$ and primes of smaller dimensions. As $\chi$ is additive on short exact sequences, one has:

$$\chi(M,N) = ab\chi(R/p,R/q)$$

(one needs to use the Vanishing part of Serre's conjectures, which is known, here)

So one can conclude that $\chi(R/p,R/q)>0$! But this has been open for about 50 years, so I doubt your statement is known (for all regular local rings).

Comment: All of this is standard technique, of course. It was first used by Hochster to show that small Cohen-Macaulay conjecture implies Serre's Positivity. 